# Excel Macro - Hide and Unhide based on cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I want to set up for Excel Macro to automatically hide/unhide entire row based on the values in Column D.

e.g. If the value in D3 = 0, then hide
If the value in D4 = 1, then unhide

Only variables are 0 and 1 to indicate whether the row needs to be hidden.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it goes in the code for the worksheet, not a module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$D$3" And Target.Value = 0 Then
Rows(7).Hidden = True
End If
If Target.Address = "$D$4" And Target.Value = 1 Then
Rows(7).Hidden = False
End If
End Sub
```